# Flutter aligning GridView widget

Tags: flutter, alignment

so i want to put my **`Gridview.count`** widget in bottomCenter of my app.
As you can see, my **`Text`** widget arranges fine.I dont understand the difference beetwen those two.

What should i read or what mistake am i doing?

**That's how it looks :**

[image: what i have]

```
body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                children: const [
                  MyButton(myIcon: Icon(Icons.add), myColor: Colors.red),
                  MyButton(myIcon: Icon(Icons.remove), myColor: Colors.green),
                  MyButton(myIcon: Icon(Icons.adb), myColor: Colors.blue),
                  MyButton(myIcon: Icon(Icons.air), myColor: Colors.red),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(_wynik.toString(),
                    style: GoogleFonts.overpass(
                        fontSize: 50,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                        color: Colors.white))),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `shrinkWrap: true` to GridView

Comment: `shrinkWrap: true` is expensive try using `Exapnded` or on parent widget